# Graphite Dashboard viewer for mobile device

Tags: performance, mobile, monitoring, graphite

I have gone through various [documentations](http://www.aosabook.org/en/graphite.html) on `Graphite` (**Performance Monitoring Tool**) to explore if Graphite supports any options to view dashboards on mobile platforms  e.g. smart phones, iPad, tablets.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919478/custom-querying-in-graphite) too, I understand that Graphite allows you to query your data, both graphically and returning csv but is there any quick way to integrate Graphite with mobile devices.

Similar product OpenNMS is progressing on [iOS app](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/IOS_Client).

Answer (score 2):

Try Grafana (http://grafana.org) it is a new dashboard frontend for graphite.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question at Graphite Portal too https://answers.launchpad.net/graphite/+question/227267 but haven't heard yet. So adding my findings so far on same.

As of date Graphite doesn't offer any readily available option (mobile web interface or app) to render graphs and dashboards best suited to mobile devices i.e. phones and tablets. Graphite URL API however allows options to customize graphs as per business requirements.

The graphite webapp provides a */render* endpoint for generating graphs (and retrieving raw data). This endpoint accepts various arguments via query string parameters e.g.  defining a time window for the graph via from / until.

Below URL requests (JSON) CPU Usage metrics for app servers 401 through 405 in last 1 hour time frame. Note that removing “format=json” request attribute returns graph as image in PNG format (default Graphite behavior).

http://graphite06p.prod.s.com/render/?format=json&until=now&from=-1Hours&showTarget=applications.jboss.app40%5B12345%5Dp_prod_ch4_s_com.jvm.cpuUsage&title=JVM%20%20-%20CPU%20Utilization&_salt=1367342114.856&target=applications.jboss.app40%5B12345%5Dp_prod_ch4_s_com.jvm.cpuUsage

Enterprises can create mobile web app such that server component first fetches raw data from Graphite using above mentioned URL API and then make any required customizations before returning the HTML content back to device browser. For example, the JSON data received from Graphite can be plotted using Javascript library FLOT or ZingChart. Hybrid or native apps too can be built around this approach. Any additional inputs or suggestions are most welcome.