# Is it possible to query data from Whisper (Graphite DB) from console?

Tags: api, console, graphite, whisper

I have configured Graphite to monitor my application metrics. And I configured Zabbix to monitor my servers CPU and other metrics. 
Now I want to pass some critical Graphite metrics to Zabbix to add triggers for them.

So I want to do something like

```
$ whisper get prefix1.prefix2.metricName
> 155
```

Is it possible?

P.S. I know about Graphite-API project, I don't want to install extra app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK! I found it myself: http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/render_api.html?highlight=rawJson (I can use curl and return csv or json).

Answer was found here [custom querying in graphite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919478/custom-querying-in-graphite?rq=1)

Also see: https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/blob/master/docs/render_api.rst

Comment: It would be nice to have a solution not involving a webapp (whether accessed with a browser or curl).

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `whisper-fetch` program which is provided in the whisper installation package.
Use it like this:

```
whisper-fetch /path/to/dot.wsp
```

Or to get e.g. data from the last 5 minutes:

```
whisper-fetch --from=$(date +%s -d "-5 min") /path/to/dot.wsp
```

Defaults will result in output like this:

```
1482318960  21.187000
1482319020  None
1482319080  21.187000
1482319140  None
1482319200  21.187000
```

You can change it to json using the `--json` option.

Comment: Finding files: `find /var/lib/graphite/ -name *.wsp`